# Weird segfault and the stack trace from boost::python implies that my code is running inside an exception handler

Tags: python, c++, segmentation-fault, boost-python

I'm writing an application in Python and part of it is written in C++.

The Python code calls into the C++ library through a function called merge_charstrings.

I'm experiencing a really strange segmentation fault that only occurs under very specific circumstances. During the course of investigating this I noticed that if I set a breakpoint in the Python binding code at the point where it calls mergeCharstrings, the stack trace looks like this:

```
#0  mergeCharstrings_helper (cs1Tokens=..., cs2Tokens=...) at /home/rob/Desktop/DemoFontBuilder/libcsmerge/pycsmerge/Pycsmerge.cpp:43
#1  0x00007ffff674c27a in invoke<boost::python::to_python_value<boost::python::list const&>, boost::python::list (*)(boost::python::list, boost::python::list), boost::python::arg_from_python<boost::python::list>, boost::python::arg_from_python<boost::python::list> > (ac1=<synthetic pointer>, ac0=<synthetic pointer>, 
    f=@0xa4f698: 0x7ffff674abe0 <mergeCharstrings_helper(boost::python::list, boost::python::list)>, rc=...) at /usr/include/boost/python/detail/invoke.hpp:75
#2  operator() (args_=<optimised out>, this=0xa4f698) at /usr/include/boost/python/detail/caller.hpp:223
#3  boost::python::objects::caller_py_function_impl<boost::python::detail::caller<boost::python::list (*)(boost::python::list, boost::python::list), boost::python::default_call_policies, boost::mpl::vector3<boost::python::list, boost::python::list, boost::python::list> > >::operator() (this=0xa4f690, args=<optimised out>, 
    kw=<optimised out>) at /usr/include/boost/python/object/py_function.hpp:38
#4  0x00007ffff623513a in boost::python::objects::function::call(_object*, _object*) const () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_python-py34.so.1.54.0
#5  0x00007ffff62354a8 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_python-py34.so.1.54.0
#6  0x00007ffff623f953 in boost::python::detail::exception_handler::operator()(boost::function0<void> const&) const ()
   from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_python-py34.so.1.54.0
#7  0x00007ffff674c3c3 in operator() (this=<optimised out>, translate=0x7ffff674a900 <translateException(csmerge::CsMergeException const&)>, f=..., handler=...)
    at /usr/include/boost/python/detail/translate_exception.hpp:48
#8  operator()<bool, boost::python::detail::translate_exception<csmerge::CsMergeException, void (*)(const csmerge::CsMergeException&)>, boost::_bi::list2<const boost::python::detail::exception_handler&, const boost::function0<void>&> > (f=..., a=<synthetic pointer>, this=<optimised out>) at /usr/include/boost/bind/bind.hpp:382
#9  operator()<boost::python::detail::exception_handler, boost::function0<void> > (a2=..., a1=..., this=<optimised out>)
    at /usr/include/boost/bind/bind_template.hpp:102
#10 boost::detail::function::function_obj_invoker2<boost::_bi::bind_t<bool, boost::python::detail::translate_exception<csmerge::CsMergeException, void (*)(csmerge::CsMergeException const&)>, boost::_bi::list3<boost::arg<1>, boost::arg<2>, boost::_bi::value<void (*)(csmerge::CsMergeException const&)> > >, bool, boost::python::detail::exception_handler const&, boost::function0<void> const&>::invoke (function_obj_ptr=..., a0=..., a1=...) at /usr/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:132
#11 0x00007ffff623f71d in boost::python::handle_exception_impl(boost::function0<void>) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_python-py34.so.1.54.0
#12 0x00007ffff6233db3 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_python-py34.so.1.54.0
#13 0x000000000051c577 in PyEval_EvalFrameEx ()
#14 0x0000000000487164 in PyEval_EvalCode ()
#15 0x000000000056be90 in ?? ()
#16 0x000000000047b1c3 in PyRun_FileExFlags ()
#17 0x000000000047b5a0 in PyRun_SimpleFileExFlags ()
#18 0x00000000005c0b33 in Py_Main ()
#19 0x000000000047dbc1 in main ()
```

It looks like my code is being invoked via an exception handler, which is weird.

Here is the Python binding code:

```
#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include <CsMerge.hpp>


namespace py = boost::python;
using namespace csmerge;


static CsToken toCsToken(const py::object& obj) {
    py::extract<const char*> strExtractor(obj);
    py::extract<float> floatExtractor(obj);

    if (strExtractor.check()) {
        std::string val(strExtractor());
        return CsToken(val);
    }
    else if (floatExtractor.check()) {
        float val = floatExtractor();
        return CsToken(val);
    }
    else {
        throw CsMergeException("Charstring contains invalid token - must be number or string");
    }
}


static py::list mergeCharstrings_helper(py::list cs1Tokens, py::list cs2Tokens) {
    geometry::FLOAT_PRECISION = 20.0; // TODO

    Charstring cs1;
    for (int i = 0; i < py::len(cs1Tokens); ++i) {
        cs1.push_back(toCsToken(cs1Tokens[i]));
    }

    Charstring cs2;
    for (int i = 0; i < py::len(cs2Tokens); ++i) {
        cs2.push_back(toCsToken(cs2Tokens[i]));
    }

    Charstring merged = mergeCharstrings(cs1, cs2);

    py::list result;

    for (CsToken tok : merged) {
        switch (tok.type) {
            case PS_OPERATOR:
                result.append(tok.str);
                break;
            case PS_OPERAND:
                result.append(tok.num);
                break;
        }
    }

    return result;
}


static void translateException(const CsMergeException& ex) {
    PyErr_SetString(PyExc_RuntimeWarning, ex.what());
}


BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(_pycsmerge) {
    py::def("initialise", &csmerge::initialise);
    py::def("merge_charstrings", &mergeCharstrings_helper);

    py::class_<CsToken>("CsToken", py::init<int>())
        .def(py::init<const std::string&>())
        .def("__eq__", &CsToken::operator==)
        .def("__ne__", &CsToken::operator!=);

    py::register_exception_translator<CsMergeException>(&translateException);
}
```

Here is the Python code:

```
from pycsmerge import *


if __name__ == '__main__':
    glyph = [
        86, 'hmoveto', 74, 659, -74, 'hlineto', 'endchar'
    ]

    watermark = [
        0, -240, 'rmoveto', 16.25, 0, 'rlineto', 106.75, 417.70729053318826, 'rlineto', 106.75, -417.70729053318826, 'rlineto', 16.25, 0, 'rlineto', -114.875, 449.5, 'rlineto', 114.875, 449.5, 'rlineto', -16.25, 0, 'rlineto', -106.75, -417.70729053318826, 'rlineto', -106.75, 417.70729053318826, 'rlineto', -16.25, 0, 'rlineto', 114.875, -449.5, 'rlineto', -114.875, -449.5, 'rlineto', 0, 240, 'rmoveto'
    ]

    glyph2 = [
        472, 368, 'rmoveto', -133, 225, 258, 66, -589, -66, 257, -225, -133, -66, 133, -302, 74, 302, 133, 'hlineto', 'endchar'
    ]

    watermark2 = [
        0, -237, 'rmoveto', 28.3625, 0, 'rlineto', 274.1375, 425.96466584292557, 'rlineto', 274.13750000000005, -425.96466584292557, 'rlineto', 28.362499999999955, 0, 'rlineto', -288.31875, 448.0, 'rlineto', 288.31875, 448.0, 'rlineto', -28.362499999999955, 0, 'rlineto', -274.13750000000005, -425.96466584292557, 'rlineto', -274.1375, 425.96466584292557, 'rlineto', -28.3625, 0, 'rlineto', 288.31875, -448.0, 'rlineto', -288.31875, -448.0, 'rlineto', 0, 237, 'rmoveto'
    ]

    print('one')
    res1 = merge_charstrings(glyph, watermark)
    print('two')
    res2 = merge_charstrings(glyph2, watermark2)
    print('three')
```

The conditions under which the segfault occur are very strange indeed. In the code above, glyph2 and watermark2 seem to be dodgy data (the CGAL library compiled in debug mode rejects them), but glyph and watermark are ok. If I call merge_charstrings only once, I will never get a segfault. If I call merge_charstrings multiple times with glyph and watermark I will never get a segfault. If I call merge_charstrings with glyph and watermark first and glyph2 and watermark2 second I usually *will* get a segfault. However, if I call merge_charstrings with glyph2 and watermark2 first and glyph and watermark second, I will never get a segfault. In other words, the function succeeds on glyph2 and watermark2 only if that's the first call. Weirder still, in a pure C++ demo, I can't get it to segfault at all.

Comment: Why don't you just look at the code instead of making assumptions based on just a stack trace?

Comment: The stack trace may be wrong, try a clean build

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt You mean through the code for the Python interpreter and the boost-python library? How would that help?

Comment: @texasflood It is a clean build

Comment: "It looks like my code is being invoked via an exception handler" - read the source before making unfounded claims.